# In Rails 4 How to Test Devise Custom Registration Paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have customized the `devise` paths like this :

```
devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'signin', sign_out: 'signout', password: 'secret', confirmation: 'verification', unlock: 'unblock', registration: 'signup', sign_up: 'new' }
```

So for example it makes the user signup path like this `http://localhost:3000/signup/new`. Now the problem is, I don't know how to test this page. Here's the test for users_controller :

```
    require 'test_helper'

    class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

      test "should get signup" do
        get :signup_new
        assert_response :success
        assert_select "title", "SignUp | #{Figaro.env.app_name}"
      end

    end
```

How to visit these custom paths in my test files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably testing the wrong controller. Check your routes (`rake routes`) to see which controller is assigned to handle your Devise authentication routes. By default I believe it is `Devise::SessionsController`.

I do not think this is your intent, but it is worth mentioning that you should *not* test the devise gem.

Note that requests for ActionController::TestCase are simulated. If you want to test true requests then you should look into integration testing. A brief overview can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing)

#### UPDATE

Take a look in the Devise gem for some examples of how to log a user in [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/test/controllers/custom_registrations_controller_test.rb#L31). Notice that `include Devise::TestHelpers` is added near the top of the test class which adds a `sign_in` method.

Comment: Ok then in user's controller, how can I login a user in the tests? Even though im in the wrong controller I should be able to visit the page right? In the devise guide it tells us how to test with Capybara. But im not using it or Rspec.

Comment: I also stumbled upon this https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Testing, which shows how to directly use Warden to log a user in (Devise uses Warden under the covers).